# Trying to inject into AngularJS run block

Tags: angularjs

In an attempt to initialize my application, I'm trying to init the module the run() method as follow, but it does not compile.

the error is:

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider%20%3C-%20%24route

 Error: error:unpr
 Unknown Provider
 Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route
```

and here's the code in app.js :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage', [
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ui.dashboard',
        'kendo.directives',
       'jqwidgets'             
    ]).run(['$route', '$rootScope', init]);

    function init($route, $rootScope){
        var i = 1;
    }

})();
```

However with no dependencies, it runs through fine:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage', [
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ui.dashboard',
        'kendo.directives',
       'jqwidgets'             // Kendo UI and jQWidgets libs (loaded in index.html)
    ]).run(init);

    function init(){
        var i = 1;
    }

})();
```

Comment: `$route` is not from angular ui router. You need to include ngRoute module for angular router

Comment: @PSL - there you are again ! And you're absolutely right. I just discovered that in a different application which injects the 'ngRoute' module (Angular $route service).

Comment: Hey!! I have added answer below... Hope it works.

Comment: kudos to NJ. you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) is not part of `ui.router` module. and `ui.router` does not use [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) as well so you cannot access `$route` service inside the run block because it does not exist. Try including `ngRoute` if you need to use it (But you already have a `ui.router` so i am not sure).

```
 angular.module('rage', [
       'ngRoute' //<-- Here
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ui.dashboard',
        'kendo.directives',
       'jqwidgets'             
    ]
```

Or just remove `$route` from the dependency list.